# Почему я всегда получаю 0 в Math.random()

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Не понимаю почему всегда возвращает 0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У приведения типов приоритет выше, чем у умножения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.